# In which case three projetive points exist on the same projetive line $RP^2$.

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

How to prove that three different points in $RP^2$,
$[x_1;y_1;z_1]$
$[x_2;y_2;z_2]$
$[x_3;y_3;z_3]$
Are on the same projective line $RP^2$ if and only if the det of the row's matrix of the three points (above) equals 0.
Can you help in this, and by the way suggest me a good book on the topic of Projective space and geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using homogeneous coordinates, the lines in $\Bbb R^3$ through the origin correspond to the points of $\Bbb RP^2$, and the*planes* through the origin correspond to the *lines* of $\Bbb RP^2$.

So, the 3 given points are collinear in $\Bbb RP^2$ iff the 3 given vectors are in a common plane (iff they don't span the whole space $\Bbb R^3$ iff they are linearly dependent) iff their determinant is $0$.

Comment: Thanks! , Is there a way to prove it with calculating?  ,I guess i got it but not totally.

Comment: Why are the lines and planes in $R^3$ through the origin?

Comment: One way to visualize it is to put the ordinary plane on the affine plane $S:z=1$ in $\Bbb R^3$. Then any nonzero vector determines a unique point in the projectivized plane of $S$ by taking the intersection of the line of $v$ (through the origin) with $S$. If the vector is parallel to $S$, i.e. lies on the $x,y$-plane, then it determines a 'point in infinity'.